# CMake is not linking library as expected (How to force linking)

Tags: c++, cmake, linker

***Situation:***

Let's say I have 2 libraries (libA.a, libB.a) I want to use in an executable (exec.cpp). 
My `libA` includes `foo(x)` which is used in `libB`'s function `bar(y)`. Thus, I include the header of `libA` in `libB`, and then include the header of `libB` in my executable and link both:

*A.h:*

```
#ifndef LIB_A_INCLUDED
#define LIB_A_INCLUDED

int foo(int x);

#endif
```

*A.cpp:*

```
int foo(int x) {
    //DO stuff
}
```

*B.h*

```
#ifndef LIB_B_INCLUDED
#define LIB_B_INCLUDED

#include <A.h>

int bar(int y);

#endif
```

*B.cpp:*

```
int bar(int y) {
    foo(y);
    //more stuff
}
```

The CMakeLists file for the two libaries looks like this (for `libB` there's also an `include_directories` call to include A.h):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(libA)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_library(libA A.h A.c)
```

*Exec.cpp:*

```
#include<B.h>

int main() {
    bar(42);
    return 0;
}
```

The CMakeLists file for the executable looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(Exec)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
include_directories("PATH_TO_HEADER_A/A.h" "PATH_TO_HEADER_B/B.h")

add_executable(Exec main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(Exec "PATH_TO_LIB_A/libA.a;PATH_TO_LIB_B/libB.a")
```

***Problem***

This does not work! It yields:

```
/usr/bin/ld: PATH_TO_LIB_B/libB.a(B.c.o): in function `bar':

/usr/bin/ld: PATH_TO_LIB_B/B.cpp:95: undefined reference to `foo'
```

However, when I change Exec.cpp to:

```
#include<B.h>

int main() {
    bar(42);
    foo(31415);
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles and works *as expected* - it seems the linker does not link `libA` when no functions of `libA` are used in exec.cpp directly, even though these functions are used in `libB` which is definitely using `foo`.

***Question***

Is there a way to force the link? How do I get this to work?

Comment: Link order of the libraries matters, see that answer to duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix/24675715#24675715

Comment: What's the correct order then? Because I did think about the order - thats why libA is first in the target_link_libraries list.
It makes sense to me why that would be the case but shouldn't the "lower" (in my case libA as it's used in libB which in turn is used by the executable) libraries be linked first?
Also why does it work once I use 'foo(x)' in the executable without changing anything else?

Comment: A citation from the referenced answer: "In general, if library A depends on library B, then libA MUST appear before libB in the linker flags.". In your case `libB` depends from the `libA`, so `libB` should come **before** `libA` in `target_link_libraries` call.

Answer (score 1):

Your `libB` doesn't know about the implementation of `foo` (providing the header for `libA` is not enough). One way to resolve this is to use [`target_link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) in your `libB` CMake file to link `libA` to `libB`. You could change your `libB` CMake to look something like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(libB)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_library(libB B.h B.cpp)
target_include_directories(libB PUBLIC PATH_TO_HEADER_A)    
target_link_libraries(libB PUBLIC "PATH_TO_LIB_A/libA.a")
```

---

Based on feedback, adding an example showing how the ordering to the linker *matters*, per the linked duplicate question. It appears each library is built by a separate instance of CMake, so this may be more pertinent; the executable's CMake should **re-order** the linked libraries to place `libB` first. (Also, removing the header names from the `include_directories()` call, as it is not necessary.):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(Exec)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
include_directories(PATH_TO_HEADER_A PATH_TO_HEADER_B)

add_executable(Exec main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(Exec PATH_TO_LIB_B/libB.a PATH_TO_LIB_A/libA.a)
```

Comment: As this is the first answer on MANY of the simmilar questions on the internet, I have tried it (pretty much in all possible permutations). **This does not fix the problem.**

Comment: @The_Reto Ok, it may not have worked if you create each library in a separate instance of CMake (running CMake three separate times, but I expanded my answer to include an example of the situation described in the linked duplicate question.